# Check if two out of three equal something

Tags: python

For a school project, I'm working on a TicTacToe game in python with an AI. Now i'm kinda stuck for a while. So i use this code to check if there is a winner:

```
playField = [['.','.','.'],['.','.','.'],['.','.','.']]
def checkWinner(L):
    return ((playField[0][0] == L and playField[0][1] == L and playField[0][2] == L) or #Line 1 horizontal
        (playField[1][0] == L and playField[1][1] == L and playField[1][2] == L) or #Line 2 horizontal
        (playField[2][0] == L and playField[2][1] == L and playField[2][2] == L) or #Line 3 horizontal
        (playField[0][0] == L and playField[1][0] == L and playField[2][0] == L) or #Colomn a vertical
        (playField[0][1] == L and playField[1][1] == L and playField[2][2] == L) or #Colomn b vertical
        (playField[0][2] == L and playField[1][2] == L and playField[2][2] == L) or #Colomn c vertical
        (playField[0][0] == L and playField[1][1] == L and playField[2][2] == L) or #Diagonal left-top to right-bot
        (playField[0][2] == L and playField[1][1] == L and playField[2][0] == L)) #Diagonal right-top to left-bot
```

And this is working great, but for my ai i want to check if either he has two on a row or the 'enemy' has two in a row. So basically i want to check if two out of three equal 'L' and I have no clue on how to rewrite the function do that, or another way to check if two out of three equal 'L'.

Help would be great!

**Greetings,
Jeroen**

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Write a `check_row` function that receives the three values and checks for two out of three. Then call it for each of the 8 rows.

Answer (score 2):

The rows of the board are

```
[playField[i] for i in range(3)]
```

The columns of the board are

```
[[playField[i][j] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

The diagonals are

```
[playField[i][i] for i in range(3)]
```

and

```
[playField[2-i][i] for i in range(3)] (thanks, @volcano!)
```

So you now are dealing with lists of threes (or lists of lists of threes).

---

Suppose you have a list such as

```
a = [10, 20, 10]
```

Then

```
sum(e == 10 for e in a)
```

Returns the number of items equals to 10. If this number is 2, then

```
sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda (_, e): e == 10)[0][0]
```

will give the index of the (single) item that is not 10.

---

I think those are all of the building blocks you need.

Comment: Also _[playField[2-i][i] for i in range(3)]_ - for another diagonal.

Comment: @volcano Thanks - absolutely right, missed that one.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot, so with this i can find how many times 'L' is used in lst, but what would be a good way to then return the index that does not equal 'L'. For example:
X . X
.  .  .
.  .  . 
Should return [0][1].

Comment: @Jeroen I think it would be good to try to do this on your own. If you get stuck, write a question about it. I could write the answer, but then you'd basically get from it how to solve a tic-tac-toe problem - not very useful in itself.

Comment: I tried to use:
def checkTwoRow(L):
    columns = [[playField[i][j] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)] #Rows
    return sum(e == L for e in columns)
And then call print(checkTwoRow("X")), but it keeps returning 0. I'm a noob in python so pardon for my stupid questions :P.

Comment: @Jeroen See update; in particular, see if you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list `foo = ['A', 'B', 'L', 'L']`, you can check the number of 'L's with `foo.count('L')`.

Comment: This would work if each posibble 'three in a row' would be an apart list, but  basically i have to check the indexes from within a list with eachother. Is this possible too?

Comment: In that case, I suppose you could construct the list containing a column using for example `[field[i][0] for i in range(3)]` for column 0, and call `.count()` on that.